# Comparing Case Class Instances with Squeryl?

Tags: scala, squeryl

How can I properly evaluate `case class` instances in `squeryl`?

```
$cat build.sbt 
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.squeryl" %% "squeryl" % "0.9.5-7"

$sbt console

scala> case class Foo(x: Int) extends org.squeryl.customtypes.IntField(x)
defined class Foo

scala> Foo(42) == Foo(42)
res0: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Lol, found the problem: https://github.com/broadinstitute/Squeryl/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/squeryl/customtypes/CustomTypesMode.scala#L29 . WhyTH would anyone do that baffles me.

Comment: I saw that too! :-/